# Swaping the color scheme of tab view indicators in SwiftUI 3

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I have a tab view defined by this code:

```swift
TabView {
    ViewOne()
    ViewTwo()
}
.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
.indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
```

This creates a tabview indicator like this. However id like to either use a darker color or swap the scheme of this one component.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `indexViewStyle` is not customizable at the moment, because the `IndexViewStyle` protocol is not public.

However, you can try to use `TabView(selection:)` init and overlay, or somehow hide the original indexView and just make your own.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what does you mean by color scheme. If you want to change the color of the indicator or remove the background of the color you can do this:

```
struct PageView: View {
    
    init() {
        UIPageControl.appearance().currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .cyan
        UIPageControl.appearance().pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(1)
        UIPageControl.appearance().backgroundStyle = .minimal
    }
    
    var body: some View {

        TabView {
            Text("First")
            Text("Second")
            Text("Third")
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page)
        
    }
}
```

`UIPageControl.appearance().currentPageIndicatorTintColor` change the color of the current page dot. `UIPageControl.appearance().pageIndicatorTintColor` change the rest of the dot. Also, in Swift 14 onwards, new style is introduced to UIPageControl. The `prominent` style which is the one you have now with the rounded view and the old style called `minimal` style which I change in my code above in `UIPageControl.appearance().backgroundStyle`.

The output of my code is

[image]

If you want to change the color accordingly to dark or light mode, you can add a `color set` in your Assets and use it.